# Multiple subqueries - SQL Server telling me to use EXISTS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(datapath,1,5) 
  FROM batchinfo 
 WHERE rowid IN (select * 
                   from qvalues 
                  where rowid in (select rowid 
                                    from batchinfo 
                                   where datapath like '%thc%'))
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(datapath, 1, 5)
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I am getting this error

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Only one expression can be specified
>   in the select list when the subquery
>   is not introduced with EXISTS.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`...where rowid in (select * from qvalues...` I'm guessing the `*` there is an issue. Specify the specific column from `qvalues` that `rowid` should be compared with (as you do in your second subselect); as it is, you're telling SQL Server to compare `rowid` to a complete row.

Comment: +1: The IN clause (in SQL Server) only supports one column on either side of the evaluation.  MySQL's the only one I've seen that does tuples...